# Java - give child class to a method taking parent class as parameter

Tags: java, inheritance

`ABTeacher` and `ABStudent` is child class of `ABUser`

And in `applyStudentChange` I have `Collection<ABStudent> ABStudents`

I want to call  `changeABUser(Collection<ABUser> ABUsers)` in  `applyStudentChange`  but the collection I have got is a collection of child class, how should I call `changeABUser(Collection<ABUser> ABUsers)` ?

I tried call this way`changeABUser((Collection<ABUser>) ABStudents)`, and this cast does not seem to work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the following member type for your collection:

```
.... changeABUser(Collection<? extends ABUser> users) ....
```

Comment: No. The method `changeABUser` needs to take a `Collection<? extends ABUser>` that is: a collection whose member type is ABUser or a subtype thereof.